# Python: Can't save to CSV

Tags: python, api, csv

I have a script that pulls information from an API and is supposed to write it to a CSV file which I have in the same directory. For some reason, all the code seems to execute fine but the CSV never actually contains any data. Am I missing something crucial? I've checked the documentation for the CSV module but can't find anything.

Here is my code:

```
import time, json, requests, csv

with open('data.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['time','last','vwap','high','low','open','vol']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    writer.writeheader()

    def btstampTime():
        bitStampTick = requests.get('https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/')
        return bitStampTick.json()['timestamp']

    def btstampLast():
        bitStampTick = requests.get('https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/')
        return bitStampTick.json()['last']

    def btstampVWAP():
        bitStampTick = requests.get('https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/')
        return bitStampTick.json()['vwap']

    def btstampHigh():
        bitStampTick = requests.get('https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/')
        return bitStampTick.json()['high']

    def btstampLow():
        bitStampTick = requests.get('https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/')
        return bitStampTick.json()['low']

    def btstampOpen():
        bitStampTick = requests.get('https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/')
        return bitStampTick.json()['open']

    def btstampVol():
        bitStampTick = requests.get('https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/')
        return bitStampTick.json()['volume']


    while True:
        timestamp = btstampTime()
        last = float(btstampLast())
        vwap = float(btstampVWAP())
        high = float(btstampHigh())
        low = float(btstampLow())
        open = float(btstampOpen())
        vol = float(btstampVol())

        writer.writerow({'time': timestamp,
                         'last': last,
                         'vwap': vwap,
                         'high': high,
                         'low': low,
                         'open': open,
                         'vol': vol})

        print('Time: ', timestamp)
        print('Last =', last)
        print('VWAP =', vwap)
        print('High =', high)
        print('Low =', low)
        print('Open =', open)
        print('Volume =', vol)
        print('')

        time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: Did you check data you get from web? Maybe the site blocked you.

Comment: You got a lot of functions that basically do the same thing. Try to minimize the code.

Comment: Are you looking at the `.csv` file while the script is still running, right after it's written the first line? In that case, the output may not be flushed to disk yet. To test whether that's the issue, you can add an explicit `flush` after writing the row, or open the file unbuffered or line-buffered, or just ^C the script after you're sure it should have written something.

Comment: This is a highly wasteful way to do this. You make a call to the API for every seperate piece of information, including the timestamp, so it's not really valid anyway, although it may not matter for your purposes..

Comment: @TigerTV.ru yeah this script generates 70 calls in 10 minutes, the max is 600. Plus the print shows you if the data is there in the shell.

Comment: @abarnert I'll try the flush method, but what do you mean by ^C?

Comment: why do you use `open` as a var? When I commented `btstamp`s functions and in the `while` loop I set the output vars as a strings, csv was filled.

Comment: @TigerTV.ru Oh, in the while True? Does it conflict with the csv open function? And do you mind sharing your modified code so I can understand the difference you mentioned better?

Comment: @Johan: https://onlinegdb.com/rkH_A7iFM

Comment: The `while True:` at the end is an infinite loop that will only exit if there's an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is working (and optimized :)) solution. Bear in mind that info will be written to file, but it is possible that OS won't update file size visually in real time.

```
import os
import csv
import time
import requests

csv_file = open('data.csv', 'w')
field_names = ['time', 'last', 'vwap', 'high', 'low', 'open', 'vol']
writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=field_names)
writer.writeheader()

while True:
    info = requests.get('https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/').json()
    writer.writerow({'time': info['timestamp'],
                     'last': info['last'],
                     'vwap': info['vwap'],
                     'high': info['high'],
                     'low' : info['low'],
                     'open': info['open'],
                     'vol' : info['volume']})
    csv_file.flush()
    os.fsync(csv_file.fileno())
    time.sleep(60)

    # this line is optional, you can delete it.
    print('Info appended.')
```

Comment: Why don't you just call `json()` once? This seems wasteful too.

Comment: @denis-rasulev Thank you so much for this rework! This runs perfectly.

Comment: Why are you converting anything to float? Csv is a text format, so it gets converted right back... you could literally just pass in `info` instead.

Comment: Correct again. Thanks. +1 to your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

d = requests.get('https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/').json()
cols = ['timestamp', 'last', 'vwap', 'high', 'low', 'open', 'volume']
df = pd.DataFrame([d.get(i,'') for i in cols], cols).T
df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

Creates ouput.csv with:

```
timestamp,last,vwap,high,low,open,volume
1521332251,7831.18,8069.97,8356.40000000,7730.23000000,7860.83,11882.59781852
```

Comment: thank you, I'll try this variation too. Does this need to be nested in any way so that it repeats?

Comment: @Johan If you want to repeat this you will need some modifications.

Comment: @Johan Relooked at your case. This is overkill in this case.

Comment: I'll probably use the previous solution then